# Why does my VLOOKUP pull up the wrong info?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

I am making a sheet with drop down boxes to select items and I have a box to the right that I want to display the weight of the items.  I have an equipment sheet with the item name in column A and the weight in column B.  I have a formula to look it up:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($L$3:$L$11),"",VLOOKUP(L3:L11,Equipment!A60:D83,2))),"0")
```

I have it looking up column 2 which should be column B, but it is bringing up the wrong weight every time.  The sheet with the formula is "New Character" and the sheet with the info is "Equipment", they are the first 2 sheets on the left.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvLEqIdymBYSM4icQZGoQ5O1URvinQVGK9F24QcFTso/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not specify 4th vlookup argument so vlookup returns "approximate" result instead of "exact" result. for exact matches, the 4th argument of vlookup needs to be set to `0`